# Interpreting the Kretschmann scalar

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

How do you interpret the [Kretschmann scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar) (in general relativity)? What can you tell from it?

---

The Kretschmann scalar is defined as

$$K = R_{abcd} R^{abcd} $$

where $R_{abcd}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kretschmann scalar can be used as an indicator of [curvature singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity#Curvature) in the manifold. For instance, in the Schwarzschild black hole (given in the Wikipedia link in your post), 
$$
K\propto\frac1{r^6}
$$
so as $r\to0$, $K\to\infty$.

Comment: Is there a reasonable interpretation for other values of $K$? Such as when it vanishes, $K = 0$?

Comment: Sure: there are two other cases: (1) $K=0$, then there's no curvature (2) if $K>0$ (but finite), then the manifold is not flat.

Comment: Is (1) necessarily true?

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure on that note. I presume yes, but I'm willing to be corrected.

Comment: @KyleKanos For pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, you can have non-zero null curvature tensors, just like you can have nonzero, null vectors.

Comment: In the Kerr space-time we have $K=0$ even on the horizon. This is often interpreted as the "gravito-magnetic" and "gravito-electric" components of the gravitational field being equal. You can understand this better by considering electromagnetism; there you will also find no invariant characterizing the "strength of the elmag." field. Tensor theories are simply *tensor* theories, the field cannot be characterized by a set of fully invariant scalars. As a reference I recommend the paper on invariants by Cherubini et al. from 2002 (http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0302095v1.pdf).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The same statements would be true for various other curvature scalars.

Comment: For future readers: OP asked about this particular scalar and I provided a use that I was aware of. That there are other scalars that can provide the same (or similar) information does **not** mean that this one does not do so. I also did not claim that this is its only use. Ergo, user4552's remark is a *non sequitur* and should be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

For vacuum solutions, since the Ricci tensor $R_{ab}$ vanishes, the Kretschmann scalar is equal to the norm of the Weyl tensor, $K = C_{abcd}C^{abcd}$.  This means it is telling you something about the tidal forces at a given point.  I might use $K^{1/2}$ to characterize the strength of the tidal forces.  This can be used in Schwarzschild or Kerr spacetimes to see that the tidal forces go like $M/r^3$ (at least in the equatorial plane for Kerr).

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer.