# Significance of Kretschmann scalar to flat spaces?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, curvature

If you are given a spacetime embedded with a particular metric tensor that satisfies the vacuum field equations of general relativity, how do you confirm that you aren’t simply dealing with a Minkowski spacetime that has been changed via some exotic coordinate transformation?

Or, more specifically if I have an exact solution to the vacuum field equations that has a Kretschmann scalar value of $0$. Is this just the Minkowski spacetime in a different coordinate system?

Comment: Not necessarily. Take any subset of Minkowski space or quotients of Minkowski space as counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks @Slereah. Can you think of an example in hard language. For example, the following line element satisfies the field equations $(ds)^2= ...$ and has a K scalar of $0$ but is not equivalent to Minkowski space.  I am an Applied mathematician and have studied GR entirely via tensor calc and have avoided diff geom which can often be my downfall in these situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A zero Kretschmann scalar does not mean the Riemann tensor is zero. For example in the Kerr metric the sign of $K$ can change as we move towards the black hole, and that means it necessarily passes through zero. For details of this see [this paper on the Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9912320).

There is some related discussion in [Interpreting the Kretschmann scalar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150050/interpreting-the-kretschmann-scalar).

Comment: In my particular case I have a zero Riemann tensor, zero Kretschmann scalar and also a metric tensor that identically satisfies the vacuum field equations.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin if the Riemann tensor is zero the the spacetime is Minkowski

Comment: so would you describe the Riemann tensor, among other things, as a device to determine whether or not you may simply be describing Minkowski space that may just be expressed in exotic coordinates?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin yes, calculating the Riemann tensor is the only sure guide. No matter what your coordinate system the Riemann tensor will always be zero for Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: Back to the drawing board it would appear